# Batch file to unzip files and run Python script

Tags: python, batch-file, unzip

I have a project where I need to unzip files containing a `.xls` file and then run a Python script to convert the file to `.xlsx`. I need to do this by executing a Windows Batch file through the Windows Task Scheduler. I found some code on Superuser to unzip the file, but it does not loop and you have to explicitly type the name of the file you want to unzip.

Here's the unzip code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
Call :UnZipFile "C:\Test Folder\" "C:\Test Folder\File1.zip"
exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
IF "%~dp0"=="" GOTO Continue
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
```

Here's my Python code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--sourcefilepath')
parser.add_argument('--sourcefilename')
args = parser.parse_args()

fname = r"{sourcefilepath}{sourcefilename}".format(sourcefilepath=args.sourcefilepath,sourcefilename=args.sourcefilename)

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname)
wb.SaveAs(fname + "x", FileFormat = 56)

wb.Close()                                 
excel.Application.Quit()
quit()
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to have the python script do the unzipping and looping, and just have a batch file call the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d "%~dp0" || exit /b 1

for %%A in (*.zip) do (
    call :UnZipFile "%cd%\" "%%~fA"

    for %%B in (*.xls) do (
        echo python mypython.py --sourcefilepath "%cd%" --sourcefilename "%%~nxB"
        del "%%~B"
    )
)
exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
if "%~dp0" == "" exit /b 1
set "vbs=%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist "%vbs%" del /f /q "%vbs%"

(
    echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
    echo If NOT fso.FolderExists("%~1"^) Then
    echo fso.CreateFolder("%~1"^)
    echo End If
    echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application"^)
    echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace("%~2"^).items
    echo objShell.NameSpace("%~1"^).CopyHere FilesInZip, 16
    echo Set fso = Nothing
    echo Set objShell = Nothing
) > "%vbs%"

cscript //nologo "%vbs%"
if exist "%vbs%" del /f /q "%vbs%"
```

Just some minor fixes to special characters
needing escaping in the `echo` commands.
Replaced `goto continue` with `exit /b 1`.
Added simple `for` loop to get all zip filenames.

It will get xls files in the current directory
and delete the xls files once the python script
has done the SaveAs task.

Remove `echo` in front of python command if checked as OK.

---

Or try this python code which does the
looping, unzipping, and xls to xlsx.

```python
import win32com.client as win32
import argparse
import glob
import os
import zipfile

def xls_to_xlsx(filename, filepath=None):
    if not filepath:
        filepath = os.getcwd()

    fname = os.path.join(filepath, filename)

    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname)
    wb.SaveAs(fname + "x", FileFormat = 56)

    wb.Close()
    excel.Application.Quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for zip_file in glob.iglob('*.zip'):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file) as r:
            r.extractall()

        for xls_file in glob.iglob('*.xls'):
            xls_to_xlsx(xls_file)
            os.remove(xls_file)
```

It does not set current working directory
which Task Scheduler can set it, or you
can add it into the python script to set it.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing everything in Python.